# How can I restrict the creation of password in Zimbra mail server?

Tags: email, passwords, restriction, zimbra

After I instaled the Zimbra mail server I noticed that when creating a new user I can insert any type of password ex "123456" "password"...what I want is the password to contain at least one uppercase letter and a digit in order to be a valid password. How can I set that on zimbra mail server ?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure these behaviour at COS level using attribute "zimbraPasswordMinUpperCaseChars".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest also this attributes:

```
zimbraPasswordMinLength

zimbraPasswordMaxLength

zimbraPasswordMinUpperCaseChars

zimbraPasswordMinLowerCaseChars

zimbraPasswordMinPunctuationChars

zimbraPasswordMinNumericChars

zimbraPasswordMinDigitsOrPuncs
```